# Average and Lowest and Highest Temperature - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, debugging

This calculator is designed to accept user input for the purpose of calculating and reporting average temperatures. I've got the it completed for the most part but I'm running into an issue where low temps that have a different amount of digits than the high, example: 9 and 10 or 95 and 110, the script is valuing the low temp higher than the high temp. Under neath is the javascript I'm using. Unfortunately I can't add a screenshot yet but the output response on entering a low of 9 and a high of 10 is:

Please enter a low temperature less than the high temperature.

```
(function(){
var temperatures = [];
var lowest = 150;
var highest = 0;
var lowestDate;
var highestDate;
var lAverage = 0;
var hAverage = 0;

var table = $('table');

function addTemps() {
    'use strict';
    var table = "<table><tr><th style='width:110px'>Date</th><th>Low Temperature</th><th>High Temperature</th></tr>";
    var lTemp = $('lTemp').value;
    var hTemp = $('hTemp').value;
    if (((parseFloat(lTemp) != parseInt(lTemp, 10)) || isNaN(lTemp) ||
    (parseFloat(hTemp) != parseInt(hTemp, 10)) || isNaN(hTemp)) ||
    (lTemp > 150) || (hTemp < 0) || (lTemp>hTemp)) {
        if ((parseFloat(lTemp) != parseInt(lTemp, 10)) || isNaN(lTemp)){
            table += '<tr><td colspan="3">Please enter a number for low temperature.</td></tr></table>';
        }
        if ((parseFloat(hTemp) != parseInt(hTemp, 10)) || isNaN(hTemp)){
            table += '<tr><td colspan="3">Please enter a number for high temperature.</td></tr></table>';           
        }
        if ((lTemp > 150) || (hTemp < 0)) {
            table += '<tr><td colspan="3">Please enter a number below 150 for low, or a number greater than 0 for high temperature.</td></tr></table>';
        } 
        if (lTemp>hTemp) {
            table += '<tr><td colspan="3">Please enter a low temperature less than the high temperature.</td></tr></table>';            
        }
        $('output').innerHTML = table;          
    }
    else {
        lTemp = parseInt(lTemp);
        hTemp = parseInt(hTemp);
        var newDate = new Date((new Date().getTime())-(temperatures.length * 86400000));
        temperatures.push([newDate,lTemp,hTemp]);
        table = createTable(table);
        $('output').innerHTML = table;          
    }
    return false;
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    $('theForm').onsubmit = addTemps;
}

function createTable(tbl){
    lAverage=0; hAverage=0;
    for (var i = 0; i<temperatures.length; i++) {
        var date = ''+(temperatures[i][0].getMonth()+1)+"/"+temperatures[i][0].getDate()+"/"+temperatures[i][0].getFullYear();
        var low = temperatures[i][1];
        var high = temperatures[i][2];
        tbl += '<tr><td>'+date+'</td><td style="text-align: right">'+low+'</td><td style="text-align: right">'+high+'</td></tr>';
        if (low < lowest){
            lowest = low;
            lowestDate = date;
        } 
        if (high > highest){
            highest = high;
            highestDate = date; 
        }
        lAverage+=temperatures[i][1];
        hAverage+=temperatures[i][2];
    }
    lAverage=(lAverage/temperatures.length).toFixed(1);
    hAverage=(hAverage/temperatures.length).toFixed(1);
    tbl+='<tr class="summaryRow"><td>Averages</td><td style="text-align: right">'+lAverage+'</td><td style="text-align: right">'+hAverage+'</td></tr>';
    tbl+='<tr class="summaryRow"><td colspan="3">The lowest temperature of '+lowest+' occured on '+lowestDate+'.</tr>';
    tbl+='<tr class="summaryRow"><td colspan="3">The highest temperature of '+highest+' occured on '+highestDate+'.</tr>';
    tbl+='</table>';
    return tbl;
}

function $(elementID){ 
    if (typeof(elementID) == 'string') { 
        return document.getElementById(elementID);
    }
}

window.onload = init;
})();
```

I'm assuming this is an error in the addTemps function with parseFloat or parseInt but I'm stuck on what to actually modify to avoid this issue.

Comment: Some of your if statements are comparing strings instead of numbers: `(lTemp>hTemp)`

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I think I'd just been looking at it a little to long. I am running into a problem though with output after attempting to convert the strings. If I use either    (parseFloat(lTemp)>parseFloat(hTemp)) or    (parseInt(lTemp)>parseInt(hTemp)) does issue the error message but it also doesn't log user input or make the comparison. Any guidance there?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts.  I could not test this code in  repl.it, so it might have some rough edges.
If I correctly understand what this code is supposed to do..

Two main issues were:

1. You were comparing strings to numbers in several locations.
2. Your `addTemps()` function always returned `false` -- is this correct?

   *I actually don't remember how onSubmit works as I've not used JQuery or forms in ages.

   Adjust the return value from `addTemps` appropriately, if I got that part mixed up.*
3. Not technically wrong, but you can use "convenience variables" to cache calculations/conversions.  They are essentially "free" in JS.  This can make Code easier to read, and compiler doesn't have to keep re-doing the same calc.

```
(function(){
// could avoid "magic numbers" in code with:
var min_valid_hiTemp = 0;
var max_valid_loTemp = 150;

// initialize vars
var temperatures = [];
var lowest  = 150;    // max_valid_loTemp;
var highest = 0;      // min_valid_hiTemp;
var lowestDate  = '';
var highestDate = '';
var lAverage = 0;
var hAverage = 0;

var table = $('table');

function addTemps() {
    'use strict';

    var table = "<table><tr><th style='width:110px'>Date</th><th>Low Temperature</th><th>High Temperature</th></tr>";
    var lTemp = $('lTemp').value;
    var hTemp = $('hTemp').value;

    // convenience variables
    loTemp_float = parseFloat(lTemp);
    loTemp_int   = parseInt(lTemp, 10);
    hiTemp_float = parseFloat(hTemp);
    hiTemp_int   = parseInt(hTemp, 10);
    loTemp_isNAN = isNaN(lTemp);
    hiTemp_isNAN = isNaN(hTemp);


    // print error message if input was invalid
    if ( (loTemp_float != loTemp_int) ||
         (hiTemp_float != hiTemp_int) ||
         loTemp_inNaN || hiTemp_isNan ||
         (loTemp_int > hiTemp_int) ||
         (loTemp_int > 150) || 
         (hiTemp_int < 0)
        ){
          if ((loTemp_float != loTemp_int) || loTemp_isNAN){
              table += '<tr><td colspan="3">Please enter a number for low temperature.</td></tr></table>';
          }
          if ((hiTemp_float != hiTemp_int) || hiTemp_isNAN){
              table += '<tr><td colspan="3">Please enter a number for high temperature.</td></tr></table>';           
          }
          // uses "magic numbers"
          if ((loTemp_int > 150) || (hiTemp_int < 0)) {
              table += '<tr><td colspan="3">Please enter a number below 150 for low, or a number greater than 0 for high temperature.</td></tr></table>';
          } 
          if (loTemp_int > hiTemp_int) {
              table += '<tr><td colspan="3">Please enter a low temperature less than the high temperature.</td></tr></table>';            
          }

        // don't call createTable() ?  
        $('output').innerHTML = table;  

        // shouldn't this block return false? - To not submit the form
        return false

    }
    // input is valid: store the temperature data
    else {
        // not necessary now - we already have variables with this info: loTemp_int, hiTemp_int
        // lTemp = parseInt(lTemp);
        // hTemp = parseInt(hTemp);

        //  curious how the number of stored temps is related to the date..? 
        var newDate = new Date((new Date().getTime())-(temperatures.length * 86400000));

        // just use the variables we already have
        //temperatures.push([newDate, lTemp, hTemp]);
        temperatures.push([newDate, loTemp_int, hiTemp_int]);

        table = createTable(table);
        $('output').innerHTML = table; 

        // shouldn't this block return true? - To submit the form
        return true
    }

    // ?? No matter what, return false?
    // I suspect you want to return false if input was invalid, and true if it was valid.
    // if so, the return values should be inside the "if" and the "else" blocks.
    // Not outside both blocks, as it is here.
    //return false;
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    $('theForm').onsubmit = addTemps;
}

function createTable(tbl){
    lAverage=0; 
    hAverage=0;

    for (var i = 0; i<temperatures.length; i++) {

        var date = ''+(temperatures[i][0].getMonth()+1)+"/"+temperatures[i][0].getDate()+"/"+temperatures[i][0].getFullYear();
        var low  = temperatures[i][1];
        var high = temperatures[i][2];

        tbl += '<tr><td>'+date+'</td><td style="text-align: right">'+low+'</td><td style="text-align: right">'+high+'</td></tr>';

        if (low < lowest){
            lowest = low;
            lowestDate = date;
        } 
        if (high > highest){
            highest = high;
            highestDate = date; 
        }

        // you already have variables "low" and "high" - may as well use them
        // lAverage+=temperatures[i][1];
        // hAverage+=temperatures[i][2];
        lAverage += low;
        hAverage += high;
    }

    lAverage=(lAverage/temperatures.length).toFixed(1);
    hAverage=(hAverage/temperatures.length).toFixed(1);

    tbl+='<tr class="summaryRow"><td>Averages</td><td style="text-align: right">'+lAverage+'</td><td style="text-align: right">'+hAverage+'</td></tr>';
    tbl+='<tr class="summaryRow"><td colspan="3">The lowest temperature of '+lowest+' occured on '+lowestDate+'.</tr>';
    tbl+='<tr class="summaryRow"><td colspan="3">The highest temperature of '+highest+' occured on '+highestDate+'.</tr>';
    tbl+='</table>';

    return tbl;
}

function $(elementID){ 
    if (typeof(elementID) == 'string') { 
        return document.getElementById(elementID);
    }
}

window.onload = init;
})();
```

*I actually don't remember how onSubmit works as I've not used JQuery or forms in ages.

Adjust the return value from `addTemps` appropriately, if I got that part mixed up.*

---

Here is a [repl version](https://repl.it/MRft/latest), that also corrects a couple typos that exist in the above code.
*note: none of the "print" statements will appear until you reply to the "add another temp" prompt with something other than `y`.* So that part of the functionality is not perfect, but you can see that the main sticky points of the logic have been correctly addressed.

```
// could avoid "magic numbers" in code with:
var min_valid_hiTemp = 0;
var max_valid_loTemp = 150;

// initialize vars
var temperatures = [];
var lowest  = 150;    // max_valid_loTemp;
var highest = 0;      // min_valid_hiTemp;
var lowestDate  = '';
var highestDate = '';
var lAverage = 0;
var hAverage = 0;

// var table = $('table');
// non html version
var table = 'table\n';

function addTemps() {
    'use strict';

    var table = 'Date' + '        ' + 'Low Temperature' + '         ' + 'High Temperature' + '\n';

    // var lTemp = $('lTemp').value;
    // var hTemp = $('hTemp').value;

    // non html version:
    var lTemp = prompt('enter low temp');
    var hTemp = prompt('enter high temp');

    // convenience variables
    var loTemp_float = parseFloat(lTemp);
    var loTemp_int   = parseInt(lTemp, 10);
    var hiTemp_float = parseFloat(hTemp);
    var hiTemp_int   = parseInt(hTemp, 10);
    var loTemp_isNAN = isNaN(lTemp);
    var hiTemp_isNAN = isNaN(hTemp);


    // print error message if input was invalid
    if ( (loTemp_float != loTemp_int) ||
         (hiTemp_float != hiTemp_int) ||
         loTemp_isNAN || hiTemp_isNAN ||
         (loTemp_int > hiTemp_int) ||
         (loTemp_int > 150) || 
         (hiTemp_int < 0)
        ){
          if ((loTemp_float != loTemp_int) || loTemp_isNAN){
              table += 'Please enter a number for low temperature.' + '\n';

          }
          if ((hiTemp_float != hiTemp_int) || hiTemp_isNAN){
              table += 'Please enter a number for high temperature.' + '\n';           
          }
          // uses "magic numbers"
          if ((loTemp_int > 150) || (hiTemp_int < 0)) {
              table += 'Please enter a number below 150 for low, or a number greater than 0 for high temperature.' + '\n';
          } 
          if (loTemp_int > hiTemp_int) {
              table += 'Please enter a low temperature less than the high temperature.' + '\n';            
          }

        // does't call createTable() ?  
        // $('output').innerHTML = table;
        // without html:
        console.log(table);
        console.log();

        // shouldn't this block return false? - To not submit the form
        return false

    }
    // input is valid: store the temperature data
    else {

        //  curious how the number of stored temps is related to the date..? 
        var newDate = new Date((new Date().getTime()) - (temperatures.length * 86400000));

        temperatures.push([newDate, loTemp_int, hiTemp_int]);

        table = createTable(table);
        //$('output').innerHTML = table; 
        // non html version
        console.log(table);
        console.log();

        // shouldn't this block return true? - To submit the form
        return true
    }

    // ?? No matter what, return false?
    // I suspect you want to return false if input was invalid, and true if it was valid.
    // if so, the return values should be inside the "if" and the "else" blocks.
    // Not outside both blocks, as it is here.
    //return false;
}

function init() {
    'use strict';

    //$('theForm').onsubmit = addTemps;

    // non html / jquery version
    if (addTemps()){
        console.log("submitted");
    }
    else {
        console.log('not submitted');
    }
}

function createTable(tbl){
    lAverage=0; 
    hAverage=0;

    for (var i = 0; i< temperatures.length; i++) {

        var date = '' + (temperatures[i][0].getMonth()+1) + 
                   "/" + temperatures[i][0].getDate() + 
                   "/" + temperatures[i][0].getFullYear();
        var low  = temperatures[i][1];
        var high = temperatures[i][2];


        tbl += date + '\t' + low + '\t\t\t' + high + '\n';

        if (low < lowest){
            lowest = low;
            lowestDate = date;
        } 
        if (high > highest){
            highest = high;
            highestDate = date; 
        }

        lAverage += low;
        hAverage += high;
    }

    lAverage = (lAverage/temperatures.length).toFixed(1);
    hAverage = (hAverage/temperatures.length).toFixed(1);

    tbl += 'Averages' + '\t' + lAverage + ' low, ' + '\t\t' + hAverage + ' high' + '\n';
    tbl += 'The lowest temperature of  ' + lowest   + ' occured on ' + lowestDate +'.\n';
    tbl += 'The highest temperature of ' + highest  + ' occured on ' + highestDate+'.\n';
    tbl += '\n';

    return tbl;
}


// window.onload = init;

var addAnother = 'y'
while (addAnother == 'y') {
  init();
  addAnother = prompt('press "y" to add another');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sheryl, this makes a lot of sense. I never even thought to set loTemp as a separate variable ahead of the comparison. As far as the "return false" issue I don't particularly understand it myself, most of this code was pre-made by the author of the textbook I'm using.

Comment: @3R4BB1T glad this has helped.  I added a non html-version and a link to a corresponding repl that you can play with and see how it works.

Comment: @3R4BB1T the repl.it version also corrects a couple typos that remain in the first version I pasted.

Comment: @3R4BB1T, It's always appreciated when OP can "upvote" and "accept" answers they useful.  It's free, easy, and unlike money, you never run out.  You'll get points too.  Ya, very cheap labor!